# How to Apply PercentFormatter for a NumberBox in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I want to add Percentage at the end(0%-100%). It shows % correctly, but it add more zeros at the end like this,

[image]

```
        double number = 75;
        NumberBoxnumberBox = new NumberBox {  };
        PercentFormatter percentFormatter = new PercentFormatter();
        percentFormatter.FractionDigits = 0;
        percentFormatter.IntegerDigits = 1;
        numberBox.NumberFormatter = percentFormatter;
        numberBox.Value=number;
```

Comment: Give a try `numberBox.Value=percentFormatter.Format(number));`

Comment: I tried it already, it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually expected. The PercentFormatter takes an arbitrary number and formats it as using the (mathematical) rule that `1=100%`. So in your case, `75` is `7500%`. To achieve the affect of appending a "%" to numbers, you can write your own formatter and use that:

```cs
public class AppendPercentageSignFormatter : INumberFormatter2, INumberParser
{
    public string FormatInt(long value)
    {
        return value.ToString() + "%";
    }

    public string FormatUInt(ulong value)
    {
        return value.ToString() + "%";
    }

    public string FormatDouble(double value)
    {
        return value.ToString() + "%";
    }

    public long? ParseInt(string text)
    {
        // Cut off the percentage sign at the end of the string and parse that.
        return long.Parse(text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1));
    }

    public ulong? ParseUInt(string text)
    {
        // Cut off the percentage sign at the end of the string and parse that.
        return ulong.Parse(text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1));
    }

    public double? ParseDouble(string text)
    {
        // Cut off the percentage sign at the end of the string and parse that.
        return double.Parse(text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1));
    }
}

// And later in your UI:
double number = 75;
numberBox.NumberFormatter = new AppendPercentageSignFormatter();
numberBox.Value = number;
```

Comment: We can't set numberBox.value=AppendPercentageSignFormatter.FormatDouble(75.0). Because it returns string. If we try to set using numberBox.Text, it won't take

Comment: Because that's not how you use formatters with NumberBox. I've added an example on how to use with NumberBox to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using **"PercentFormatter"** with **"SignificantDigitsNumberRounder"** classes.

**1. Page.xaml:**

```
<NumberBox Value="{x:Bind local:AnyValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="0.5" Maximum="3" 
   NumberFormatter="{x:Bind local:PctFormatter}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline" 
   SmallChange="0.05" LargeChange="0.5" PlaceholderText="Between 50%-300%" />
```

**2. Page.xaml.cs:**

```
public static PercentFormatter PctFormatter => new PercentFormatter() {
   FractionDigits = 0, NumberRounder = new SignificantDigitsNumberRounder() {
      SignificantDigits = 3
   }
};
```